# Adding a class to the manifest in Android

Tags: java, android

I ran into this problem just now, scratching my head on how to tackle this problem.

Basically, I have `MainActivity`, and a lot of classes in my app, such as `RootUtils`, `LegalProsecution`, `CameraSilencer`, etc, etc. `MainActivity` is the only activity in this app, and the rest is just classes for executing code, showing dialogs, etc.

The particular class I have problem with is `LegalProsecution.java`, which is responsible for opening a dialog on first launch and show the users legal stuff. However, the stack trace points to line 48, which is simply `dialog.show();`

Here is the full stack trace:

```
05-01 19:01:08.075 21777-21777/ideaman924.camerasilencer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: ideaman924.camerasilencer, PID: 21777
       Theme: themes:{}
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ideaman924.camerasilencer/ideaman924.camerasilencer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:340)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
           at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
           at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)
           at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
           at ideaman924.camerasilencer.LegalProsecution.warningShow(LegalProsecution.java:48)
           at ideaman924.camerasilencer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Anybody know what's the problem? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is LegalProsecution.java, which handles dialog creation:

```
package ideaman924.camerasilencer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class LegalProsecution {

    Context context = MyApp.getContext();

    AppPreference appprefs = AppPreference.getInstance(context);

    public void warningShow()
    {
        if(appprefs.loadSettings() == 1);
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApp.getContext());
            builder1.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.warning));
            builder1.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.warning_description));
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.yes),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Got promise from user, now setting first_run to 1
                            appprefs.storeSettings(1);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }
            );
            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.no),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Okay, cool, bye! No CS for you!
                            dialog.cancel();
                            ((Activity)context).finish();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
            );
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
            alert1.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is MyApp.java, which I used as a workaround to solve the stupid context issue:

```
package ideaman924.camerasilencer;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApp extends Application
{
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme to AppCompat?

Comment: are you using `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: Share your dialog creation code.

Comment: Okay, wait a moment...

Comment: Added the code blocks. One thing to note, I tried changing the theme to AppCompat, I've tried switching to Theme.AppCompat, still does this stupid thing. I'm using API23, not the preview N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
MyApp.getContext();
```

Create a constructor, and assign a context like

```
public LegalProsecution(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then when you create an instance, Create like this

```
LegalProsecution lp = new LegalProsecution(MyActivity.this);
```

Then don't forget to create alert dialog using the `context` you just assigned to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Okay, at public LegalProsecution(Context context), I'm getting a "class or interface required" error. Any help?

Comment: @ideaman924 No it shouldn't show these kind of error. Are you sure you created this method at top of LegalProsecution class ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you meant to make the class into a constructor. Fixed. However, I've run into another problem. this.context returns "Cannot resolve symbol this.context"

Comment: Ohh bro, may be you didn't create `private Context context` variable in `LegalProsecution` class.

Comment: This worked, however now I have problems with appprefs. AAAHHH kill me now... I hate debugging. But I'll find it somehow. I'll report back with results.

Comment: Hahaha Don't blast your mind, code when your mind is cool enough. And it's the proper solution, your issue will be fixed.

Comment: Nope. The contexts were all fixed, deleted MyApp.java but still getting issues with themes.

Comment: Is it possible that I need to somehow add the classes to the manifest?

Comment: @ideaman924 No !! Activities are added to manifest, classes are not, MyApp.java is may be not responsible for the error.  Why you extend Application instead of extending Activites or AppCompatActivity like so?

Comment: Yeah, I've thought so, too. But MainActivity is the only activity across the app, and it extends AppCompatActivity. I have no idea when you say I'm extending Application, because I am not doing that.

Comment: @ideaman924 what about this then `public class MyApp extends Application`

Comment: So I have actually removed MyApp.java, like I have said on the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending `ActionBarActivity`. Try to extends `AppCompat` instead.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` was deprecated.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes i know, but some developers still use it

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your app theme is set to AppCompat `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.light`
cause Dialog require it. 
If that's true, this is probably due to the inheritance of your main class wich set the theme to an other one.